# renew section command with args

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, multicol, parameters

How can I renew the section command to include some additional arguments and start a multicolum section?
something like:
`\section{title}{toc-title}{picture}{second picture}{subtitle}{author}`

I just succeeded with a new environment, but now I have to add the TOC entries manually (and sections are not displayed in TexmakerX)

here a sample:

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={ 32cm , 47cm }]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{palatino,times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{calc}

\newenvironment{mysection}[5]{
  %before
  \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.6\linewidth}
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[height=40pt]{picts/pic-#3.jpg}
    \framebox{first picture}
    \par
    \textbf{#2}\par
    \rule{\linewidth-50pt}{3pt}
    \section*{#5}
    \rule{\linewidth-50pt}{3pt}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.4\linewidth}
%    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picts/pic-#4.jpg}
    \noindent\framebox(280,200){this is the main an big picture}
    \end{minipage}

  \begin{multicols}{4}
  By\textbf{ #1}
  \bigskip

}
{ %after
\end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mysection}{authorname}{subtitle}{pict}{anotherpict}{this is the section title}


\lipsum[1-4]

\end{mysection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @ThierryBlanc When posting a MWE, please, remove packages that are not necessary. In your MWE you just need `graphicx` `multicol` and `lipsum`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2, #5}` in the definition of the `mysection` environment (I have included both the toc-title, `#2`, and the author, `#5`, in the text passed to the toc).

Comment: @ThierryBlanc you are welcome. Since it seems that my answer solves your problem you can accept the answer (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)